# Set a Form Input Value by choosing an Item from my Unordered list

Tags: jquery, html

Hi
I have a long Unordered list that is always visiable on my website.
I need a user to be able to click on one of the List Items and that Item to appear as the value in my Form type=text.
I want to use Jquery to do this.
Pleas can anyone help me ?

Comment: Usually, it's a good idea to post your current code so we can see what you've tried, and what you're working with. Without those details (the html mark-up and the jQuery/JS you're using) we can only supply generic answers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work, though you'll have to fill in the various `id`s to make it specific to your page:

```
$('#IDofUL li').click(
function(){
    var valueString = $(this).text();
    $('#inputID').val(valueString);
});
```

Comment: @Marc, you're welcome; if this helped then please feel free to up-vote and/or accept the answer =)